# Next.js build fails on Vercel and locally

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, react-typescript

Im building my first Next.js website, but for some reason I am getting a build error. This happens both locally and on Vercel, but I was able to get a working local build at some point (which doesnt work anymore now).

This is my package.json:

```
    {
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.17",
        "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.5.1",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
        "@fontsource/dm-sans": "^4.5.9",
        "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.7.9",
        "@types/react-table": "^7.7.14",
        "framer-motion": "^9.0.4",
        "mongodb": "^4.8.1",
        "next": "latest",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
        "react-query": "^3.39.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "18.7.5",
        "@types/react": "16.9.17",
        "typescript": "4.6.3"
      }
    }
```

These are the errors I get when running `npm run build` (I get the first one locally and on vercel, second one only on vercel)

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types .Failed to compile.

./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/index.d.ts:1212:28
Type error: ';' expected.

  1210 | declare type HydratedFeatureDefinition = {
  1211 |     isEnabled: (props: MotionProps) => boolean;
> 1212 |     Feature: typeof Feature<unknown>;
       |                            ^
  1213 |     ProjectionNode?: any;
  1214 |     MeasureLayout?: typeof MeasureLayout;
  1215 | };
```

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/index.d.ts:1212:28
Type error: ';' expected.
```

---

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I find it odd that this gives an error, because I don't use framer-motion anywhere myself. It is bundled with ChakraUI. After a build, I also get weird errors where my VSCode says it cant find certain imports.

[image: vscode ts error screenshot]

What I have tried:

1. Deleting node_modules & package-lock.json, running npm i again
2. Uninstalling framer-motion
3. Setting nodeversion in Vercel from 18 to 16 and 14 (none work)

To be honest I am completely lost with what to do and where to begin. Hopefully someone reading this post has an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! It turned out I needed to update Typescript with npm install -D typescript@latest. On the Typescript Github it was recommended to install it globally, but it is better to install it as a dev dependency. A pull request has been opened for this issue by someone working on TS